# How to filter the list by using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list mentioned below.

```
var fakedata = new Dictionary<Gateway, List<FeMeasurementValues>>()
{
    {
        new Gateway { SiteId = 1, FirmwareVersion = "1.1.1", ConnectivityStatus = GatewayConnectivityStatus.ReadyToConnect },
                    new List<FeMeasurementValues>() { new FeMeasurementValues { MeasurementName = "MsgLRRID", Values = new List<FeValue> { new FeValue { Value = "FFFF123", Horodate = DateTime.Now } } } }
    },
    {
        new Gateway { SiteId = 2, FirmwareVersion = "1.1.2", ConnectivityStatus = GatewayConnectivityStatus.Connected },
                    new List<FeMeasurementValues>() { new FeMeasurementValues { MeasurementName = "MsgLRRID", Values = new List<FeValue> { new FeValue { Value = "GH67123", Horodate = DateTime.Now } } } }
    },
    {
        new Gateway { SiteId = 3, FirmwareVersion = "1.1.3", ConnectivityStatus = GatewayConnectivityStatus.Disconnected },
                    new List<FeMeasurementValues>() { new FeMeasurementValues { MeasurementName = "MsgLRRID", Values = new List<FeValue> { new FeValue { Value = " ", Horodate = DateTime.Now } } } }
    },
    {
        new Gateway { SiteId = 4, FirmwareVersion = "1.1.1", ConnectivityStatus = GatewayConnectivityStatus.Connected },
                    new List<FeMeasurementValues>() { new FeMeasurementValues { MeasurementName = "MsgLRRID", Values = new List<FeValue> { new FeValue { Value = "SA67123", Horodate = DateTime.Now } } } }
    }
};
```

I have two methods

1. "GetPublicNetworkUsedCount()" which needs to return the count of Value which starts with "FFFF"
   So, In this case output should be 1.
2. "GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount()" which needs to return the count of Value which does not starts with "FFFF" and which includes empty values.
   So, In this case output should be 3.

Below is what i have tried:

```
private static string GetPublicNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values)
{
    var countofPublicNetwork = values.Where(x => x.Value.Any(f => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF")));
    return countofPublicNetwork.Count().ToString();
}

private static string GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values)
{
    var countofPrivateNetwork = values.Where(x => x.Value.Any(f => !x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF")));
    return countofPrivateNetwork.Count().ToString();
}
```

I'm getting the wrong output as 0 for GetPublicNetworkUsedCount and 1 for GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount.

Please  help me.

Comment: How exactly are you calling those two? They don't accept FeMeasurementValues which is what you have in the first dictionary.

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] which can be executed to demonstrate the problem?  It's not clear to me how specifically these two pieces of code are being used together.

Comment: Note that the two conditions in your code are not opposites if your FeMeasurementValue has multiple FeValues. If it has two, one starting with FFFF and one not then it can be both public and private by those implementations. If it has no FeValues then it is neither.

Answer (score 4):

`x.Value.Any()` will return true as soon as the condintion inside is true. which leads to return 1 convertet to a number.

to get alll entries starting with `FFFF` remove the Any part like:

```cs
var countofPublicNetwork = values.Where(x =>x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));
```

you can get the count directly if you substitute `.Where()` with `.Count()` like Mark mentioned in his comment.

```cs
var countofPublicNetwork = values.Count(x =>x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));
```

Comment: The question is for getting the count, not an enumerable. I think you can simply substitute `Where` with `Count`.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti thats correct. I just picked up his example and adjusted it. I added it to the anwser. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List<FeValue>`, where each object has a string `Value`. You are treating the string as a collection and going one step to deep, the `.Any(` is not needed.

So the check should just be

```
values.Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF")).Count();
```

Or just

```
values.Count(x => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments:

```
//             vv I'd recommend to return int
private static string GetPublicNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values)
{                                                       // vv Any doesn't make sense here: this is a string
    var countofPublicNetwork = values.Where(x => x.Value.Any(f => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF")));
    return countofPublicNetwork.Count().ToString();
}

private static string GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values)
{
    var countofPrivateNetwork = values.Where(x => x.Value.Any(f => !x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF")));
    return countofPrivateNetwork.Count().ToString();
}
```

So, I'd do something like this:

```
private static int GetPublicNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values) 
    => values.Count(x => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));


private static int GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount(List<FeValue> values)
    => values.Count(x => !x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));
```

The returned `int` can then be stringyfied if need be.

---

Maybe I'd even do

```
public static class FeValueListExtensions
{
    public static int GetPublicNetworkUsedCount(this List<FeValue> values) 
    => values.Count(x => x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));


    public static int GetPrivateNetworkUsedCount(this List<FeValue> values)
    => values.Count(x => !x.Value.StartsWith("FFFF"));
}
```

which can then be used as

```
// Assume we have a List<FeValue> defined as
List<FeValue> feValues = ...
var publicCount = feValues.GetPublicNetworkUsedCount();
```